# How to access array element sequentially in for loop in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

I have 5 dataset:

```
data1=rand(1,1000)
data2=rand(1,1000)
data3=rand(1,1000)
data4=rand(1,1000)
data5=rand(1,1000)
```

I have to select the values sequentially and a non-repetitive way.

My whole pocess is for i=1,

```
Result1(index1) = data1(index1)+data1(2)
Result2(index1) =  data2(index1)+data2(index2)
result3(index1) = data1(index3)+data2(index1)+data3(index1)
result4(index1) = data1(index4)+data3(index2)
```

And i want to continue this process for i=200,where array index should be in sequential way.
like following way:

```
Result1(index2) = data1(index5)+data1(6)
Result2(index2) = data2(index3)+data2(index4)
result3(index2) = data1(index7)+data2(index3)+data3(index3)
result4(index2) = data1(index8)+data3(index4)
```

Thank you for your time and considerations.

Comment: What are `index1` and `index2` and so forth? How are they related to `i`? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## METHOD 1: using a FOR loop (SLOW)

```
data1=rand(1,1000);
data2=rand(1,1000);
data3=rand(1,1000);
data4=rand(1,1000); % ! not used
data5=rand(1,1000); % ! not used

% Preallocation of memory for better performance
result1 = zeros(1,200);
result2 = zeros(1,200);
result3 = zeros(1,200);
result4 = zeros(1,200);
% Main loop
for i=1:200
    i1 = (i-1)*4+1; % takes values 1, 5,  9, 13,...
    i2 = (i-1)*4+2; % takes values 2, 6, 10, 14,...
    i3 = (i-1)*4+3; % takes values 3, 7, 11, 15,...
    i4 = (i-1)*4+4; % takes values 4, 8, 12, 16,...
    result1(i) = data1(i1)+data1(i2);
    result2(i) = data2(i1)+data2(i2);
    result3(i) = data1(i3)+data2(i1)+data3(i1);
    result4(i) = data1(i4)+data3(i2);
end
```

## METHOD 2: using MATRIX indexing operations (FAST)

```
imat = 1:200;
i1mat = 4*(imat-1)+1;
i2mat = 4*(imat-1)+2;
i3mat = 4*(imat-1)+3;
i4mat = 4*(imat-1)+4;
result1 = data1(i1mat)+data1(i2mat);
result2 = data2(i1mat)+data2(i2mat);
result3 = data1(i3mat)+data2(i1mat)+data3(i1mat);
result4 = data1(i4mat)+data3(i2mat);
```

You can also avoid to construct `imat`,`i1mat`,`i2mat`,`i3mat`,`i4mat` and just do:

```
result1 = data1(1:4:800)+data1(2:4:800);
result2 = data2(1:4:800)+data2(2:4:800);
result3 = data1(3:4:800)+data2(1:4:800)+data3(1:4:800);
result4 = data1(4:4:800)+data3(2:4:800);
```

All the methods give the same results.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and considerations.